# $d_1:ax+2y+4=0$; $d_2:3x-4y+12=0$; $|d_1d_2|=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, analytic-geometry

> $d_1:ax+2y+4=0$
>
> $d_2:3x-4y+12=0$
>
> $d_1$ // $d_2$
>
> $|d_1d_2|=?$

This is a slightly modified version of a university entrance examination problem set up by the experts at this specific university itself.

I don't know what is meant by $|d_1d_2|$. I searched the internet for what could have been meant by this expression, but I couldn't find it. When taken as the distance between two parallel lines, the answer can be found to be $4$.

I want to object to the problem for the ambiguity on what is meant by $|d_1d_2|$. During the rush of the exam, I thought the problem asked for the absolute value of the multiplication of the two lines, for whatever it would be.

Is this expression ,$|d_1d_2|$, algebraically correct and does it mean the distance between two parallel lines?

Comment: Yes, I wouldn’t say it’s very ambiguous, it’s the distance between the given parallel lines.

Answer (score 2):

*You can safely skip the computations in 1. and go directely to 2. if you are only interested in the notation.*

1. **Distance between $d_1$ and $d_2$.** Two straight lines represented by the equations 
   $$Ax+Bx+C=0\qquad\text{ and } \qquad A'x+B'x+C'=0$$
   are parallel if and only if 
   $$ AB'=A'B .$$
   This means that $$d_1:ax+2y+4=0, \qquad \text{ with }\qquad A=a, B=2, C=4$$  and 
   $$d_2:3x-4y+12=0\qquad \text{ with }\qquad A'=3, B'=-4, C'=12$$
   are parallel if and only if $$ a(-4)=3(2)\iff a=-\frac{3}{2} .$$
   Now, let $d$ be a straight line with equation 
   $$d:\tilde{A}x+\tilde{B}y+\tilde{C}=0.$$
   This line $d$ is perpendicular to e.g. $d_1$ if and only if 
   $$A\tilde{A}+B\tilde{B}=0\iff \tilde{A}=-\frac{B\tilde{B}}{A} ,\qquad \text { 
    with   } A=a=-\frac{3}{2}, B=2,$$
   which means that 
   $$d: \tilde{A}x+\tilde{B}y+\tilde{C}=0\iff -\frac{B\tilde{B}}{A}x+\tilde{B}y+\tilde{C}=0 \iff Bx-Ay-\frac{A\tilde{C}}{\tilde{B}}=0.$$
   Hence $d$ is represented by
   $$d: 2x+\dfrac{3}{2}y+\frac{3}{4}\tilde{C}=0.$$
   For $\tilde{C}=0 $, we get a line $d'$ parallel to $d$:
   $$d': 2x+\dfrac{3}{2}y=0.$$
   If we compute the coordinates of the intersection points of $d_1$ and $d_2$  with $d'$, we find that 
   $$
   \left\{ 
   \begin{align}
   -\frac{3}{2}x+2y+4&=0 \\[2ex] 
   2x+\frac{3}{2}y&=0
   \end{align}
   \right. \iff \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{l}
   x=\dfrac{24}{25} \\[2ex]
   y=-\dfrac{32}{25}
   \end{array}
   \right. 
   $$
   and
   $$
   \left\{ 
   \begin{align}
   3x-4y+12&=0 \\[2ex] 
   2x+\frac{3}{2}y&=0
   \end{align}
   \right. \iff \left\{ 
   \begin{array}{l}
   x=-\dfrac{36}{25} \\[2ex] 
   y=\dfrac{48}{25}.
   \end{array}
   \right. 
   $$
   As you claimed the distance between $d_1$ and $d_2$ is indeed $4$, because
   $$\sqrt{\left( \frac{24}{25}+\frac{36}{25}\right) ^{2}+\left( -\frac{32}{25}-
   \frac{48}{25}\right) ^{2}}=4.$$

   2. **Notation**

      - As for the notation of the [*length of the line segment*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LineSegment.html) $AB$, that is the distance between two points $A$ and $B$ is normally written $\overline{AB}$. However, $\overline{AB}$  may also denote the *line segment* itself ([here](https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/BasicTerms/BTnotation.html)) instead of the *length of the line segment*, which is then denoted by $AB$. Another notation for the *line segment* is  $[A,B]$ ([here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_(math%C3%A9matiques))). The symbol $|\ldots|$ may denote *Euclidean norm* or *Euclidean length or magnitude* ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Brackets))
      - Concerning the notation $|d_1d_2|$, I've never seen it before, but from the context, the answer to your last question "does it mean the distance between [the given] parallel lines?" seems reasonable to assume so.

Answer (score 1):

Since $d_1||d_2$ we have $-{a\over 2} = {3\over 4}$ so $a= -{3\over 2}$. Now take any point $T(x_0,y_0)$ from one line, say $d_1:\;\; -3x+4y+4=0$ and calcluate it distance from $d_2$, say by formula: $$ {|ax_0+by_0+c|\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$